# ¿Cómo cambiar color de letra?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

Estoy cambiando un poco el estilo de la página que estoy creando con Angularjs. Se que no tiene que ver con el diseño pero no se cómo cambiar el color de la letra que tengo en la barra principal de mi página.
Aqui os dejo el link de la página: http://localhost:58498/

Quiero cambiar las palabras Aplicattion name y todas las siguientes de la barra azul en color blanco.

Os dejo aqui el layout donde se modifica la barra al igual qie el HTML y el script.
Gracias de antenamo.

```js
angular.module('formApp', [])
.controller('formAppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.radioOptions = [
        { name: 'Crédito hipotecario', value: 'Crédito hipotecario' },
        
        { name: 'Crédito personal', value: 'Crédito personal' },
    ];
    $scope.contenedor = {};
    $scope.contenedor.cantidad = "";
    $scope.contenedor.cuota = "";
    $scope.contenedor.plazos = "";
    $scope.contenedor.tipo ="";

    $scope.formulario = {}
    $scope.formulario.cantidad = 0;
    $scope.formulario.plazos = 0;
    $scope.formulario.tipo = "";

    var logresultado = function (respuesta) {
        $scope.contenedor.cantidad = respuesta.cantidad;
        $scope.contenedor.cuota = respuesta.cuota;
        $scope.contenedor.plazos = respuesta.plazos
        $scope.contenedor.tipo = respuesta.tipo;
    };

    $scope.showMe = false;


    $scope.myForm = function () {

        var baseURL = 'http://localhost:58498/api/cuota?';
        var cantidad = 'cantidad=' + $scope.formulario.cantidad;
        var plazos = '&plazos=' + $scope.formulario.plazos;
        var tipo = '&tipo=' + $scope.formulario.tipo;

        $http.get(baseURL+cantidad+plazos+tipo).success(function (respuesta) {

            console.log(respuesta)
            logresultado(respuesta);

        console.log('entra aqui')
        $scope.showMe = !$scope.showMe;

        })
       
    }
});
```

```css
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-color:#ede7e7">
    <div style="position:center ; color: #1D66EE">
        <h1>//ABANCA</h1>
    </div>

    <p class="lead">
        Préstamos en 24H.
        Haz tus cuentas.
    </p>

</div>

<div class="row" ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formAppCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <form action="http://localhost:58498/api/Cuota" class="form-horizontal"
              method="get" role="form" id="formulario-cuotas">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="Cuotas">¿Cuánto quieres pedir?</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                       data-val-cuotas="El campo de las Cuotas está vacío. No es válido"
                       data-val-required="El campo Cuotas es obligatorio." id="Cuotas"
                       name="cantidad" type="number" value=""
                       ng-model="formulario.cantidad">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                      data-valmsg-for="Cuotas" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <p>
                "Con el préstamo 24h puedes pedir a partir <br>
                de 500€, pero para cantidades de hasta 3000€ <br>
                tiene que ser en la "<a href="/es/tarjetas/tarjetas-credito/tarjeta-visa-clip" target="_blank">
                    modalidad de
                    tarjeta <br>
                </a>
                ".Por eso este simulador empieza en 3000€ que <br>
                es lo mínimo que puedes pedir en la modalidad <br>
                de préstamo. Ten en cuenta que no puedes <br>
                solicitar más de lo que cuesta lo que vayas <br>
                financiar."
            </p>


            <br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Plazo" class="control-label">¿Cuándo deseas devolverlo?</label>
                <input class="form-control" data-val="true"
                       data-val-cuotas="El campo de los plazos está vacío. No es válido"
                       data-val-required="El campo Plazos es obligatorio." id="Plazos"
                       name="plazos" type="text" value=""
                       ng-model="formulario.plazos">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text--danger"
                      data-valmsg-for="Plazos" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>

            <p>
                "Puedes devolverlo en un plazo maximo de 96 meses,<br>
                osea, 8 años"
            </p>

            

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-check" ng-repeat="option in radioOptions">
                            <input type="radio" ng-model="formulario.tipo" value="{{option.value}}" ng-required="!formulario.tipo">
                            {{option.name}}

                        </label>

                    </div>
            
            

            <br>
            <br>


        </form>

        <button id="btnenviar" name="btnenviar" class="btn btn-primary input-group">
            ENVIAR
        </button>
        <br>

        <div>
            <div>
                <button ng-click="myForm()">
                    NG-ENVIAR
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div ng-show="showMe">
            <form method="get" action="http://localhost:58498" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="respuestaform">

                <br>
                <br><h3>Resultado:</h3>

                <div id="resultado"></div>
                <br>
                <h4>Cantidad</h4>
                <div>{{contenedor.cantidad}}</div>

                <h4>Cuota</h4>
                <div>{{contenedor.cuota}}</div>

                <h4>Plazos</h4>
                <div>{{contenedor.plazos}}</div>

                <h4>Tipo</h4>
                <div>{{formulario.tipo | json}}</div>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

@*</div>*@


<!-- /ko -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " style="background-color:#5882FA">
        <div class="container" style="color:white">
            <div class="navbar-header" >
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "HelpPage" }, null)</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("SPAViews", required: false)
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")*@
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/banco")
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si en un link pones localhost es imposible que nosotros podamos acceder, ya que localhost, como su nombre propio indica, es para indicar que estás en un host local, interno para ti pero el cual no es externo para el resto.

Comment: Para el tema de cambiar de color la letra de algún sitio simplemente pon `color: #fff` por ejemplo para tener tus letras en blanco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No podemos acceder a tu link pero supongo que lo que quieres cambiar es el color del texto que haya contenido dentro de `navbar-header`. Simplemente añádele `color: #ffffff` o `color: white` en tus estilos CSS.

Ejemplo:

```css
#div{
  background-color:#5882FA;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">Hola</div>
```

Comment: vale perfecto! gracias!